# How Can add signature from excel using outlook

Tags: excel

please where is the error? why the code don work?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwb2j.png)

Sub SendBillsByEmail()
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

```
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For i = 2 To LastRow
   
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutlookMail
        
        .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
        .CC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2)
        .BCC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3)
        .Subject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4)
        .HTMLBody = "<p>" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1) & _
                    "<br><span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 1) & _
                          Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5), "#,##0") & " IQA" & "</span>" & _
                    "<br>---------------------------------------------------" & _
                    "<br>" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, 1) & vbCrLf & _
                    "<br><span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(5, 1) & _
                          Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5), "#,##0") & " IQA" & "</span>" & _
                    "<br>---------------------------------------------------" & _
                    "<br>" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(6, 1) & _
                    "<br><span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(7, 1) & _
                          Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5), "#,##0") & " IQA" & "</span></p>"" & " <br> " & " <img src='C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\k.png'/>"
     
                
           

     
     
     
     
     '.Send
     .Display

    End With
  
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
Next i

Set OutlookApp = Nothing
```

End Sub